# How to redirect every single visitor to a different directory like hongkiat.com

Tags: redirects

I had my website on http://rohbits.com but I had to delete it completely and create a new one in http://www.rohbits.com/blog. I have redirected all the traffic that is sent to `rohbits.com` to `www.rohbits.com/blog` but when anyone visit `rohbits.com/blah-blah-blah`, it takes them to a 404 error page provided by the hosting service which in my case is hostgators. I have been searching for a answer for a long time and then one day I visited a blog (`www.hongkiat.com/blog`) who have their blog directory similar to mine and after some research I found out that, `www.hongkiat.com/blog`, was initially `hongkiat.com` and after one year they have shifted it to different directory.

Whenever I go to `hongkiat.com`, I get redirected to `www.hongkiat.com/blog` and when I type something like this after the link `hongkiat.com/blah-blah-blah`, it still gets redirected to `www.hongkiat.com/blog`. Someone told me the other day that "This will only work if you have the same post on the new directory" but i don't think that `hongkiat.com` had any post like this one `hongkiat.com/blah-blah-blah`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you redirected trafic from `rohbits.com` to `www.rohbits.com/blog`?

If you have used a .htaccess file, it's easy to do what you want

```
    //Rewrite to www
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rohbits.com[nc]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rohbits.com/ [r=301,nc]
```

The .htaccess file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

Comment: buddy i used the default redirection tool that is available in my cpanel. Anyway, i will try this one. Thanks for your help buddy :)